# None accesses all the elements in a numpy array. How to bypass this?

Tags: python

Hello this is the code block that one-hot encodes a DNA sequence. What happens is that for 'n' it is mapping 1 in all 4 positions in the 2nd axis. I want to avoid using an if-else in the following code.

```
seq = 'nnnactgactgnnnnn'
onehot = np.zeros((len(seq), 4))
mapper = {'a':0,'c':1,'g':2,'t':3,'n':None}

for i in range(len(seq)):
    onehot[i][mapper[seq[i]]] = 1
```

output:

```
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

How can I assign **0** for **n** while using the mapper dict.

tldr: using **None** is accessing all the positions for a row. How to solve that?

Comment: If the question is just: what key can I put in `array[key] = value` such that nothing is actually bound to `value` afterwards, the answer is simple, there is no such key. Why don't you want to use if exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
mapper = {'a':[1,0,0,0],'c':[0,1,0,0],'g':[0,0,1,0],'t':[0,0,0,1],'n':[0,0,0,0]}
```

And then append the corresponding encoding according to sequence.

Edit: Might be faster.

```
seq = 'nnnactgactgnnnnn'
onehot = np.zeros((len(seq), 4))
mapper = {'a':0,'c':1,'g':2,'t':3,'n':None}
result = {'a':1,'c':1,'g':1,'t':1,'n':0}
for i in range(len(seq)):
    onehot[i][mapper[seq[i]]] = result[seq[i]]
```

Comment: assigning arrays would increase the time complexity by ~1.5 times.

Comment: nice solution. this should be faster. Thanks. (can't upvote because of my low rep)